# tcpmon - http and soap message

Tags: http, soap

First of all, I would like to apologize for the lack of research, this is kind of urgent.

Are soap messages binded in http request/header?
If yes, can I view soap messages using tcpmon?

Is there any other way to view soap messages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use TCPMon no problem.  Just create a listener, on say port 9999, and set your Target Hostname and Port # to the machine that is serving the requests.  Change your client to make the call to localhost:9999 and you'll see all the traffic come through.

Answer (score 0):

> Are soap messages binded in http request/header?

Yes - but usually in the body of the request (i.e. as a post).

> can I view soap messages using tcpmon?

I'm guessing you're refering to [Apache tcpmon](http://ws.apache.org/commons/tcpmon/) or [this](http://www.hep.man.ac.uk/u/rich/Tools_Software/tcpmon.html) ... or [this](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wpdoc/v6r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.wp.ent.doc/wps/wsrpr_trbl.html)...or...? Don't know. If not you might try [pastmon](http://pastmon.sourceforge.net/)

C.